# Генерация врагов и биндинг переменных

Tags: javascript, разработка-игр

Делал небольшую игру на js и svg с использованием ractive.js для того чтобы проще было взаимодействовать с элементами на странице. Но как позже выяснилось ractive не работает с динамически добавленными элементами и следовательно созданный враг просто стоит столбом, а генерация этих же врагов вообще не предоставлялась возможным (или просто я криворукий). Гугл ничего подходящего не выдал. По этому если кто знает, как правильно генерировать элементы и взаимодействовать с ними (менять свойства для движения и т.д.) или есть ссылки на полезные статьи, скиньте пожалуйста, буду благодарен, а то неохота опять на грабли наступать.

Comment: Если это динамичная игра, то лучше использовать canvas (и готовые движки типа phaser.js).

Comment: @VladimirGamalian на сколько я понял, phaser.js имеет множество готовых фич, мне бы для начала велосипеды пописать, да и попроще.